# Would this run async?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am doing two calls that can (ideally would) be run concurrently. The first call ultimately hits a database and the second a web API. The catch is that neither of the execution paths are async. I’ve been trying to get more familiar with TPL, but am not quite there yet. If I wrapped the two method calls in Tasks, and awaited them, would this truly execute both at the same time?

Comment: Define *async*, why do you want it, what do you hope to achieve with it.

Comment: Nobody can magically answer a theoretical question about code without a real example.  (For example, I have a *vehicle* can it go *50 mph*?  Who knows it's to abstract to have a concrete answer.)

Comment: The goal would be to have the database query and api call running at the same time so that if the query takes 1 second and the api call .5 seconds, the net running time would be the longest of the two rather than the sum.

Comment: @erikPhillips I don’t see how me having boiler plate service and repo layer code somehow allows this to be more concrete. It’s a pretty straightforward action.

Comment: You are are confusing `async` (*Async Await Pattern*) and *Asynchronous*, yes you could make both run *Asynchronously* with either tasks and or the *Async Await Pattern* provided they don't rely on each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are are confusing `async` (*Async Await Pattern*) and *Asynchronous*, yes you could make both run *Asynchronously* with either *tasks* and or the *Async Await Pattern* provided they don't rely on each other

```
public async Task DoMagicStuff()
{       
    var task1 = DoDbAsync(); // Start Task
    var task2 = DoWebAsync();// Start Task

    // wait for both
    await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);
}
```

or mixture of *IO* and *CPU bound* work

```
public async Task DoMagicStuff()
{

    var task1 = DoDbAsync(); // Start Task
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => DoWebAsync());// Start Task

    // wait for both
    await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);
}
```

or without any `async`, you could use `Task.WaitAll`